# Why is mpz export not exporting anything?

Tags: c++, encryption, binary, padding, gmp

I implement RSA with padding and now I'm at the step where I have to "Write the integer x in its unique xLen-digit representation in base 256: x = x_(xLen-1) 256^(xLen-1) + x_(xLen-2) 256^(xLen-2) + ...+ x_1 256 + x_0" https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-4.1. In order to do so I thought to use GMP:

```
void * r = malloc(k*8);
size_t *countp = NULL;
cout<<mpz_export (r, countp, 1, sizeof(char), 1, 0, cypher.get_mpz_t());
```

So I want to write my cypherext "cypher" as 1 byte words. The problem is that the countp stays 0 and nothing will be written at r. Why happens this?  The debugger shows that the memory to r does not change. How should I test if there is sth. written at r?

I hand over to the Program following arguments:

7 65537 93782468134492672170511748468674155937658193260891125506584478284995324195987296031344837315335657222031743639489984562997111601299810495341282936133972309073427234516366321364103234792719904292993399124403145513062440180724693263146418179608629393861309261386560190385243255315925738842596000513744259548491

Hereby the entire code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

//Encryt or  decrypt with RSA
mpz_class RSA(mpz_class m, mpz_class e,mpz_class N)
{
    mpz_class rop;
    mpz_powm(rop.get_mpz_t(), m.get_mpz_t(), e.get_mpz_t(), N.get_mpz_t());
    return rop;
}
//Print string under byte form with bytes separated by space
void print_serialized(string s)
{
    for(int i=0;i<(int)s.length();i++){
        if(i%8==0)
            cout<<" "<<s[i];
        else
            cout<<s[i];
    }
}

// Fill byte wit0 leading 0's
string fill0(string x)
{
    string y;
    while((int)x.length()%8!=0)
    {
        y='0';
        x=y+x;
        y="";
    }
    return x;
}
int main(const int argc, const char * const argv[])
{
    if(argc!=4)
    {
        cout<<"Usage [Message] [Exponent] [Modulus]";
        return -1;
    }

    const mpz_class m(argv[1]), e(argv[2]), N(argv[3]),c;
    mpz_class n;
    int mlen,k,PSlen,c1=0;

/*-------------------Encrypt----------------------*/

    mlen=(mpz_sizeinbase(m.get_mpz_t(), 2))/8;
    if((mpz_sizeinbase(m.get_mpz_t(), 2))%8!=0)
        mlen=mlen+1;
    k=(mpz_sizeinbase(N.get_mpz_t(), 2))/8;
    if((mpz_sizeinbase(N.get_mpz_t(), 2))%8!=0)
        k=k+1;
    PSlen=k-mlen-3;
    if(mlen>k-11)
    {
        cout<<"ERROR: Message too long";
        return -1;
    }
    string PS, buffer;
    while(c1<PSlen||c1<8){
        n=0;
        while(n==0)
            n=rand()%256;
        //cout<<endl<<n<<" "<<n.get_str(2);
        if ((int)n.get_str(2).length()!=8)
            buffer=fill0(n.get_str(2));
        else buffer=n.get_str(2);
        PS=buffer+PS;
        c1++;
    }
//generate EM = 0x00 || 0x02 || PS || 0x00
//length of EM will be 3bytes + PSlength bytes => calculate length of PS
    string EM;
    for(int i=0;i<14;i++){
        EM.push_back('0');
    }
    EM.push_back('1');
    EM.push_back('0');

//EM  || PS || 0x00
    EM=EM+PS;

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        EM.push_back('0');
    }

//EM  || message
    if ((int)m.get_str(2).length()!=8)
        buffer=fill0(m.get_str(2));
    EM=EM+buffer;

//Convert the encoded message EM to an integer message representative m (see Section 4.2):
    mpz_class m1(EM,2);

    mpz_class cypher=RSA(m1,e,N),rop;
//I2OSP
    mpz_class x_256=256;
    mpz_pow_ui(rop.get_mpz_t(), x_256.get_mpz_t(), k);
    if (cypher >= rop){
        cout<<"ERROR: Integer too large";
        return -1;
    }
    void * r = malloc(k*8);
    size_t *countp = NULL;
//Print string under byte form with bytes separated by space
    cout<<mpz_export (r, countp, 1, sizeof(char), 1, 0, cypher.get_mpz_t());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't allocated any storage for `*countp`. Just do `size_t count;`  and pass `&count` to `mpz_export`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this solved the problem!

Comment: But how should I cout the bits (0 & 1) from the address and not the address?